# Impact ranking in Excel

Tags: excel, ranking, impact-analysis

I have a table with name, volumes processed and accuracy percentage. I want to calculate who has more impact overall on my business based on those two data points. I tried SUMPRODUCT by giving 50 - 50 weight-age for both data points equally but I didn't get good result. Any other method I can use to know the impact/ranking?

```
+------+--------+----------+
| Name | Volume | Accuracy |
+------+--------+----------+
| ABC  |    251 | 52.99%   |
| DEF  |    240 | 70.00%   |
| FGH  |    230 | 74.35%   |
| IJK  |    137 | 84.67%   |
| LMN  |    136 | 56.62%   |
| OPQ  |    135 | 75.56%   |
| RST  |    128 | 60.16%   |
| UVW  |    121 | 70.25%   |
| XYZ  |    120 | 68.33%   |
| AJK  |    115 | 35.00%   |
| LOP  |    113 | 100.00%  |
+------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: I am not proud of it. But yes, I am asking what to calculate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look through there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid nobody here will be able to tell you what the business rules are for your business.

One approach might be to multiply volume by accuracy, then rank it, either with a formula or with conditional formatting color scales.

Depending on your business logic, you may want to put more weight on either volume or accuracy, so you may want to raise one value to the power of 2 before multiplying it with the other.

The technique is "use a formula to calculate the weighting". What that formula is will depend on your business logic. The following screenshot shows a weighting formula with simple multiplication, conditionally formatted with color scales and a rank formula in the next column.

[image]